# Passing a hash as an argument in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement a module that contains the data to be used in tests. Here is my module:

**authentication.rb**

```
module Helpers
  module Authentication
    def sign_in_as
      admin = {
        mobile_number: "123456789",
        password: "123456"
      }
    end
  end
end
```

The module is called in `spec_helper` file:

**spec_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Helpers::Authentication
end
```

The file below is my method for receiving the login credentials:

**login_screen.rb**

```
  def login_as(**hash)
    mobile_number_textfield.send_keys(hash[mobile_number])
    password_textfield.send_keys(hash[password])
    next_button.click()
  end
```

When I call the function from my module in my spec file, the credentials are not entered:

**login_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.describe('Login') do
  before(:all) do
    puts "something here"
  end

  it('should login as founder') do 
    @login_screen.login_as(sign_in_as)
  end
end
```

How could I pass a hash to my login method?

Comment: What happens? Do you see an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to works:

In my module I created a function only with a hash:

**authentication.rb**

```
module Helpers
  module Authentication
    def sign_in_as
      {
        mobile_number: '123456789',
        password: '123456'
      }
    end
  end
end
```

My **spec_helper** remains the same

**spec_helper.rb**

```
require_relative './helpers/authentication'

    RSpec.configure do |config|
      config.include Helpers::Authentication
    end
```

On my **login_screen** file, to each line that I want to send a hash value I added a symbol:

**login_screen.rb**

```
  def login_as(**hash)
    mobile_number_textfield.send_keys(hash[:mobile_number])
    password_textfield.send_keys(hash[:password])
    next_button.click()
  end
```

In my **login_spec** file, I just called `sign_in_as` function (created in my module)

Tip: In the spec file you don't need to require the module because the added line `config.include Helpers::Authentication` in the **spec_helper** file make this.

**login_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.describe('Login') do
  before(:all) do
    puts "something here"
  end

  it('should login as founder') do 
    @login_screen.login_as(sign_in_as)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use symbols as hash keys when you access it:

```
def login_as(**hash)
  mobile_number_textfield.send_keys(hash[:mobile_number])
  password_textfield.send_keys(hash[:password])
  next_button.click()
end
```

Your code probably raises error in `mobile_number_textfield.send_keys(hash[:mobile_number])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of the following:

```
def login_as(mobile_number:, password:)
  mobile_number_textfield.send_keys(mobile_number)
  password_textfield.send_keys(password)
  next_button.click()
end

def login_as(hash)
  mobile_number_textfield.send_keys(hash[:mobile_number])
  password_textfield.send_keys(hash[:password])
  next_button.click()
end

login_as({mobile_number: "02980298098", password: "password"})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Oli. I did something like this to work. I will post here my solution